# How WebDAV differs from HTTP?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, https, protocols, webdav

I have read about Webdav that it is written over http. And also looked in ruby net-dav library which uses http methods only. How it differs from http?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV

Answer (score 1):

HTTP specification defines methods `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `OPTIONS`, `DELETE` (as some more obscure ones). Moreover many web servers would not actually support/allow some of these (like `PUT`, `OPTIONS`, `DELETE`).

WebDAV adds `PROPFIND`, `PROPPATCH`, `MKCOL`, `COPY`, `MOVE`, `LOCK`, `UNLOCK` on top of this. And details specifics of the `DELETE`, when working with folders (called collections in WebDAV). It also defines a machine-readable (XML) format of directory listings (for the `PROPFIND` request).

See [RFC 4918](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4918).

The net_dav uses even the WebDAV methods (while they are syntactically still HTTP methods).